# Why PWA promotted to add to homescreen but just create chrome shortcut and not installed as apk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I check all  [add to home screen criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria), and I think I provided all of them in my PWA. When a user visits my PWA Mini-infobar is shown and when user click add to home screen, just shortcut of PWA added to home screen and not installed. PWA is not in the applications list and deep link not working.

UPDATE:

I am in Iran and I realized when my ANDRIOD device connects to VPN or be behind a proxy in other countries web APK installed fine. But if Andriod is connected to Iran network without proxy just chrome shortcut added to home screen.

Comment: Are you using a port with your URL? I think I have seen this issue when people do that. Have a public URL that others can test to make sure it does the same for them?

Comment: @Mathias Thanks for your attention. URL is teamapp.mohandes.me

Comment: Installs as WebApk on my ANDROID device just fine. Then runs as standalone when Icon is pressed. Make sure when testing on your own device that you clear out your browser and uninstall all previous icons that may be from previous tests. Deleting old things is the majority of the work when testing a PWA.

Comment: I could not run the Chrome Lighthouse tests. It timmed out. Could be a language thing. Have you run those and is the PWA light green?

Comment: @Mathias Thank for your attention again. I update my issue.

Comment: I also have the same problem, and I think it will be due to sanctions against Iran

Comment: I can confirm that this has something to do with the sanctions as well. Turned on a VPN service and everything worked perfectly.