# PWA not installed as WebApk

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I've made a PWA and it is passing all LightHouse factors. Even AddToHomeScreen popup is showing when visiting the website, but when you add it to your home screen it's not showing in the app drawer and has a chrome badge on it's icon.
I don't have any other idea what to do. Service worker is registered, Different icon sizes are registered, maskable icons registered, Webmanifest is correct.
What should i do?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54787378/11898289

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem solved. As it seems there is some sort of server side checking in chrome which tests your PWA before adding to home screen and as a result of being in Iran which is sanctioned, those tests fail and result in not a valid PWA. You just need to change your ip and install the PWA and everything would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

For a proper install on android, a WebAPK bundle to need be generated from your PWA. That is done by Chrome itself through google services behind the scene. But if for any reason (proxy or else) those services can't be reached, the webAPK will not be generated. And you'll end up with a shortcut to your site on the home screen instead of a properly installed PWA.

You can find more details about the problem here:
[WebAPK creation failures on Android over VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336077/webapk-creation-failures-on-android-over-vpn)

for more on WebAPK see : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks