# Force Chrome to Generate WebAPK Insted of Add to Home Screen

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, webapk

from ver.7 of android by adding webapp to device home screen, chrome logo appear in bottom right corner of icon for added item, and this is not good. for solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060253/how-to-remove-chrome-logo-from-pwa-app-home-screen-link-android-o-preview), best suggestion for me is using webAPK instead of webapp.i try to create simple web page for check webapk creation process.
according to content of this link [WebAPKs on Android](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks) :

> Installing a PWA on Android does more than just add the Progressive
> Web App to the user's Home Screen. Chrome automatically generates and
> installs a special APK of your app. We sometimes refer to this as a
> WebAPK.

and for doing this, according  [Install criteria](https://web.dev/install-criteria/#criteria), site must meet the following criteria:

- The web app is not already installed
- Meets a user engagement heuristic
- Be served over HTTPS
- Includes a [Web App Manifest](https://web.dev/add-manifest) that includes:

  - short_name or name
  - icons - must include a 192px and a 512px icon
  - start_url
  - display - must be one of fullscreen, standalone, or minimal-ui
  - prefer_related_applications must not be present, or be false
- Registers a service worker with a fetch handler

  - Starting in mid-2021, Chrome will require that the fetch event handler return a valid response when the device is offline, see [Improving Progressive Web App offline support detection](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/improved-pwa-offline-detection/) for complete details and timelines.

by preparing this list ,'add X to Home Screen' menu item rename to 'install X' but, after install process, chrome logo already exist.
it seems that install process not happen or start and fail and only create shortcut happen.
i also search internet for find any exist wepPAK example but not found.
for example https://airhorner.com/ or https://www.makemytrip.com/ has same problem

any body can help me what can i do for create webAPK or remove chrome logo?
tanks.

**UPDATE**:

by thanks of [mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3749219/mathias) for his suggestion, i installed [lighthouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk/related) plugin in chrome, check and fix all item in generated report.

[lighthouse report after fix all item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWy0G.png)

but problem still exist.i don't know why.every things seem OK!

**UPDATE**:

Like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787378/why-pwa-promotted-to-add-to-homescreen-but-just-create-chrome-shortcut-and-not-i), problem solved when use VPN and i think it will be due to sanctions against Iran. down with sanctions.

Comment: If you see the chrome logo on top of your logo you are most likely just adding a shortcut to your website, not installing a PWA. Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints.

Comment: i agree. WebAPK not created at all .thanks for your suggestion. i installed the plugin, check and fix all item in generated report but problem still exist.i don't know why.every things seem ok .!

Comment: Have you double checked on a different new device? You need to make sure you totally clear out testing from previous tests.

Comment: Note: You mention that AirHorner.com does not install for you? That is a standard basic PWA so it may indicate something with the device you are using for testing. Or your network (wild guess).

Comment: checking AirHorner.com (after clear cache) in samsung s7 and s8 plus generate same result. some things like shortcut add to home screen. no apk generate and so chrome badge added to created icon. can you check it your self and notify me?thanks

Comment: AirHorner installs as expected (no small chrome logo on icon) for me on Android standard pixel 5 setup.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787378/why-pwa-promotted-to-add-to-homescreen-but-just-create-chrome-shortcut-and-not-i

Comment: @Mathias  Thanks for your attention again. Problem solved when use VPN and I think it will be due to sanctions against Iran. down with sanctions.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved when use VPN and I think it will be due to sanctions against Iran. down with sanctions.